# What transformation does `simplify` apply when both `powsimp` and `collect` do nothing?

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following expression and want to group it by powers of the variable `e`:

```py
from sympy import symbols

e = symbols('e')
expr = (
    0.363635891123757*e
    + 1.27444227529689*(0.006290933064*e + 0.526290933064)*(0.12408152*e + 0.12408152)
    + 2.76494336639746*(0.0483917928*e + 1.0483917928)*(0.12408152*e + 0.12408152)
    + 1.27444227529689*(0.12408152*e + 0.12408152)*(
        0.012581866128*e
        + 0.39*(0.006290933064*e + 0.526290933064)*(0.12408152*e + 0.12408152)
        + 0.922581866128
    )
    + 2.76494336639746*(0.12408152*e + 0.12408152)*(
        0.0967835856*e
        + 0.39*(0.0483917928*e + 1.0483917928)*(0.12408152*e + 0.12408152)
        + 1.0967835856
    )
    + 1.63807816642065
)
```

From their descriptions both [`powsimp`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#powsimp) and [`collect`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#collect) should work, however they return the expression unmodified. When I apply [`simplify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#sympy.simplify.simplify.simplify) then the expression gets simplified as expected. So I'm wondering what other type of transformation gets applied during the call to `simplify`?

```py
from sympy.simplify import simplify, powsimp, collect

print(f'{powsimp(expr) = }')
print(f'{collect(expr, e) = }')
print(f'{simplify(expr) = }')
```

This produces the following output:

```py
powsimp(expr) = 0.363635891123757*e + (0.0080174310478246*e + 0.670727414202207)*(0.12408152*e + 0.12408152) + (0.12408152*e + 0.12408152)*(0.13380056649044*e + 2.8987439328879) + (0.158134734671097*e + 0.158134734671097)*(0.012581866128*e + (0.00245346389496*e + 0.20525346389496)*(0.12408152*e + 0.12408152) + 0.922581866128) + (0.343078375616514*e + 0.343078375616514)*(0.0967835856*e + (0.018872799192*e + 0.408872799192)*(0.12408152*e + 0.12408152) + 1.0967835856) + 1.63807816642065
collect(expr, e) = 0.363635891123757*e + (0.0080174310478246*e + 0.670727414202207)*(0.12408152*e + 0.12408152) + (0.12408152*e + 0.12408152)*(0.13380056649044*e + 2.8987439328879) + (0.158134734671097*e + 0.158134734671097)*(0.012581866128*e + (0.00245346389496*e + 0.20525346389496)*(0.12408152*e + 0.12408152) + 0.922581866128) + (0.343078375616514*e + 0.343078375616514)*(0.0967835856*e + (0.018872799192*e + 0.408872799192)*(0.12408152*e + 0.12408152) + 1.0967835856) + 1.63807816642065
simplify(expr) = 0.000851550024540092*e**3 + 0.0759270659579648*e**2 + 1.42522479477876*e + 2.62459155414223
```

---

P.S.: For my use case, this expression is part of a larger expression which I cannot transform via `simplify` because I get the error described [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19353).

```
$ conda list | grep sympy
sympy                     1.8              py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you need to use expand before collect although in this case expand is enough:

```py
In [7]: expr.expand()
Out[7]: 
                      3                       2                                        
0.000851550024540092⋅e  + 0.0759270659579648⋅e  + 1.42522479477876⋅e + 2.62459155414223
```